# Prevent both blur and keyup events to fire after pressing enter in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

After pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> I would like that only the `keyup` event be fired but `blur` is fired first. How to cancel `blur` when `keyup` is fired with <kbd>enter</kbd>?

Please don't suggest to bind both `blur` and `keyup` into a single `live()` method.

```
$(".textbox").on("blur",function () { 
    alert("blur Event fired");
});

$(".textbox").on("keyup",function (event) { 
    if(event.keyCode == 13){ // Detect Enter
        alert("KeyUp fired after pressing Enter");
    }
});
```

Comment: So who says that `blur` SHOULD NOT fire? Note: `live()` is deprecated, even though this fact has nothing to do with your problem here.

Comment: try `keypress` instead `keyup` and use `on` instead of `live`

Comment: Hey, this is a pertinent question. Please reopen it. It is a real problem I just got, having to get keyup to work before blur.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Couldn't alter `class` attribute so i'd ended up with,

```
$(".textbox").on("blur",function () { 
    if($(this).attr('flag')!='1') 
        alert("blur Event fired");
});

$(".textbox").on("keyup",function (event) { 
    $(this).attr('flag','1');
    if(event.keyCode == 13){ // Detect Enter
        alert("KeyUp fired after pressing Enter");
    }
    $(this).attr('flag','0');
});
```

Answer (score 9):

**Edit**

To prevent both events from firing, you'll have to somehow mark the element before causing it to lose focus. That way, your `blur` event handler can tell if the event is the subject of a keyup, or if it legitimately lost focus. Something like this:

```
$(".textbox").live("blur",function (event) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('keyupping'))
        alert("blur Event fired");
});

$(".textbox").live("keyup",function (event) {
    $(this).addClass('keyupping');
    if(event.keyCode == 13){ // Detect Enter
        alert("KeyUp fired after pressing Enter");
    }
    $(this).removeClass('keyupping');
});
```

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/sR6zm/

---

**Original answer**

When the event for `keyup` fires, it prepares to draw the browser alert dialog, which takes focus from the document and applies it to the modal dialog. This causes the blur event to fire.

The `blur` event is then jumping in and finishing its execution context before `keyup` knows what hit it.

This is demonstrated by using something that *does not* take the focus off the element, like `console.log`: http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/7vRLW/

The order that events fire is implementation-specific, meaning that you can't rely on Firefox acting like IE. See the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings. Try the fiddle with alerts in IE, and in this case you'll see that `blur` does hit before `keyup` in IE 7 -- and `blur` doesn't fire in Chrome!

Comment: but the question is can i cancel that `blur` event firing after Pressing Enter ?

Comment: See edit. Since `blur` does not receive any keyboard information, you wouldn't be able to detect what key was involved. Indeed, they key is not the reason the element lost focus, it's the alert that's doing it.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. I'm allowing the user to edit a single field and when they press Enter or move off that field, I send an Ajax request to update it.  I found that when I pressed Enter the Ajax request was sent twice.

So rather than calling my request on Enter, I tried calling `$input.blur()` instead, and that worked!  Which got me to thinking... If the Enter key causes a blur do I even need to try to capture it?

In my case, I did not need to.  I found that all I needed was the blur because the Enter key triggered it anyway.  I'm not sure if that's 100% across all browsers, but I did test on current versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari, all of which worked fine.

So, I suggest that you either just don't capture the Enter at all, or you simply call blur() to trigger the actions you need.

Comment: good solution. For me, pressing Enter doesn't automatically fire a blur event from the input box I'm dealing with. So I have to capture the keydown event, and if it's 13, I manually fire a blur. Maybe because my input box is not inside a <form> element. I'm not sure, but it's just a heads-up to watch out that the blur event doesn't seem to always fire.

Answer (score 3):

I have an input where a user can change it, focus out or press enter.
But when you press enter both keydown and blur is triggered, so `myFunction()` gets triggered twice.

So instead of writing two separate functions  for `keydown` and `blur`, you can instead put them into a single function:

```
my_input.on('keydown blur', function (e) {

    // was it the Enter key?
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).blur();
    }

    if (e.type == 'blur') {
        myFunction();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Adding a class -- **added** in this example, in the keyup event handler and modifying the selector for the blur event will prevent the blur event handler from firing.

```
$(".textbox:not(.added)").on("blur", function () { 
    alert("blur Event fired");
});

$(".textbox").on("keyup", function (event) { 
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(event.currentTarget).addClass('added');
        alert("KeyUp fired after pressing Enter");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me, in primefaces 5.2.5

`<p:inputText onkeydown="if (event.keyCode === 13) {return false; }" value="#{myForm.name}">
    <p:ajax event="blur" update="@this" listener="#{bean.func()}" />
</p:inputText>`

Blur event was not triggered even though Enter key was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `keyup` is a trigger for `blur` event. You should add a flag when keyup fires:

```
 $('#exemple').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('#exemple').addClass('keyupfired');
            alert('whatever');
        }
    });
```

Then, when `blur` is fired, it should ask if `keyup` has already been fired too. Remember to remove the flag if you want the event to be fired when the user get off the textbox:

```
$('#exemple').on("blur", function () {
        if (!$('#exemple').hasClass('keyupfired')) {
            alert('whatever');
        }
        $('#exemple').removeClass('keyupfired');
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

It has been brought to my attention than rather then providing hints I should give more complete explanations and code examples, so here it is:
there is always the cheap way of setting a external variable:

```
var triggerBlur = true;
$(".textbox")
    .live({
       blur : function () { 
        if (triggerBlur) {// if not preceded by keyup 'Enter' event
            alert("blur Event fired");
        }
        // reset variable to true to allow the blur event to be triggered subsequently when not preceded by keyup 'Enter' event
        triggerBlur = true;
      },
      keyup : function (event) { 
        if(event.which === 13){ // Detect Enter
            alert("KeyUp fired after pressing Enter");
            triggerBlur = false;
        }
      });
```

Also it's preferable to use event.which rather than event.keyCode (see http://api.jquery.com/event.which/ to understand why), and it is recommended to use the identity operator '===' rather than the equality '==' in javascript, as the latter is broken (see [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use))

Comment: That would work once, and only once, and pollutes the global scope. Bad practice.

Comment: 'That would work once, and only once': well, that really depends on how you organise your whole code; 'pollutes the global scope' : same; ok that's a fairly cheap way indeed but then he's looking for a solution; your solution use the dom for data, that's also bad practice.

Comment: [citation needed] -- adding a class to a dom element is not bad practice.

Comment: Chris, if it is just for the sake of remembering a state, it is. I would try to avoid interacting with the dom just for that, that's not its job. And using a variable inside document.ready is not the global scope ;). You see, I won't let go :D !

Comment: Again, [citation needed].

Despite not letting go, the fact remains that the code in your answer never resets the `triggerBlur` variable to `true`, so it only works once -- this is not a functional solution.

My solution, in addition to working more than one time, is also able to cope with more than one form element on the page. In this, your code also fails to perform. I hope you realize that no amount of commentary or debate will improve the code in this answer, and that it is not a contest. Code either works, or it does not; this code does not, mine does. We're dealing with facts here.