# Vue js stop second event

Tags: vue.js

I have input with some info.

On blur event or on enter press I want to do some action
But when I press enter my input loses focus and two events are fired one after another-what do I do?

```
<input  v-on:keyup.13.prevent ='save_renamed_group(g)'
                    @blur.prevent = 'save_renamed_group(g)'>
```

UPD: I don't consider my question as duplicate of this one:
[Prevent both blur and keyup events to fire after pressing enter in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143011/prevent-both-blur-and-keyup-events-to-fire-after-pressing-enter-in-a-textbox)

simply because I want a clear and clean and nice solution to this simple and common stuff and all solutions posted there look like a little bit of hell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent both blur and keyup events to fire after pressing enter in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143011/prevent-both-blur-and-keyup-events-to-fire-after-pressing-enter-in-a-textbox)

Comment: why not just remove the enter key handler since the blur handler will be called anyways?

Comment: @thanksd interesting and clever idea

Comment: Why does your ipnut loose focus on enter? This is not the default behaviour, do you use some library for this? Maybe this library also offers an event exactly for your scenario?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**: apply **debounce** on the method.

> Debouncing essentially groups your events together and keeps them from
>   being fired too often. To use it in a Vue component, just wrap the
>   function you want to call in lodash’s _.debounce function.
>
> https://alligator.io/vuejs/lodash-throttle-debounce/

```js
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

export default {
  methods: {
    // group all function calls within 100ms together
    // no matter how many times this function is called within 100ms, only 1 of them will be executed.
    save_renamed_group: debounce(g => {
      // ...
    }, 100),
  },
};
```

*Pros:* simple

*Cons:* delayed function execution

---

**Solution 2**: store state of function execution in a variable

```js
export default {
  created() {
    // create the variable
    this.save_renamed_group_running = false;
  },
  methods: {
    save_renamed_group(g) {
      // exit if function is already running
      if (this.save_renamed_group_running) return;

      // set running to true
      this.save_renamed_group_running = true;

      // .... other logic ...

      // set running to false before exiting
      this.save_renamed_group_running = false;
      return /* something */;
    },
  },
};
```

*Pros:* immediate function execution

*Cons:* verbose